# React alternative coding style with a 'constructor'

Tags: reactjs, redux

Creating a React component the 'standard' way a `constructor` will run before any rendering and I can use `componentDidMount` etc to run before the rendering

```
export class BotShowUI extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    }
....
```

My question is in the code below how do I get a constructor *type* method or another method to run (similar to *componentDidMount*) before the rendering in the return statement ?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    const BotShowUI = ({ bot,  onClick  }) => {
        return(
            <div id={bot.id}  onClick={onClick}>
                {bot.id} : {bot.text}
            </div>  
        )
    }

    BotShowUI.propTypes = {
       bot: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
       onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    export default BotShowUI;
```

Comment: You don't. Functional components like the one you have here only let you define the render method. If you want to take advantage of other functionality, you need to use the standard class-based component definition

Comment: You can make stateless functional components stateful by using HOCs provided by recompose if you prefer more functional style. https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Answer (score 2):

Currently you cannot. Functional components are stateless. They won't always be, though. https://twitter.com/sebmarkbage/status/658713924607606784

Comment: interesting :-)